# ASP.NET: Delete User Profile with Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, gridview, asp.net-membership

I have a SQL like this;

```
select B.LoweredUserName
  from USER_BAYI A, aspnet_Users B, aspnet_Membership C
  where B.UserId = C.UserId
  AND B.UserName = A.USERNAME
```

It's getting all username in my membership database.

[image]

I want to user Gridview's delete properties for delete this users from my membership database.

My delete commands in sqldatasource is;

```
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM aspnet_Users
WHERE  LoweredUserName = @LoweredUserName" ondeleted="SqlDataSource1_Deleted"

protected void SqlDataSource1_Deleted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        DbCommand cmd = e.Command;
        string username = cmd.Parameters["@LoweredUserName"].Value.ToString();
        Membership.DeleteUser(username);
    }
```

But this doesn't even compile. Where am I doing wrong? Or can you show me a way for doing this?

Comment: Have you set DataKeyNames on the GridView? http://weblogs.asp.net/jnadal/archive/2006/02/28/439303.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the DataKeyNames on the GridView like this: `DataKeyNames="ProviderUserKey"` and set the OnDeleteCommand to some method likie this: `OnDeleteCommand="gvUser_DeleteCommand"`.

Then in the code behind implement the onDelete method like this:

```
protected void rgUser_DeleteCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem gdiItem = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
    try
    {
        string strUserKey = gdiItem.GetDataKeyValue("ProviderUserKey").ToString();
        Guid guiUserKey = new Guid(strUserKey);
        string strUserName = Membership.GetUser(guiUserKey).UserName.ToString();

        Membership.DeleteUser(strUserName);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

Just for more info, you are binding to the wrong event on the SqlDataSource. The `OnDeleted` event is fired after the record is deleted, and you need the `OnDeleting` event because it is fired before the record is deleted. In the `OnDeleting` event you can add your custom delete code and then cancel the event, but you can't do theat in the `OnDeleted` event.

Comment: Hmm. That looks nice solution. I solve it like this; `protected void SqlDataSource1_Deleting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DbCommand cmd = e.Command;
        string username = cmd.Parameters["@LoweredUserName"].Value.ToString();
        Membership.DeleteUser(username, true);
    }`

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes, it's similar. You delete the user in the SqlDataSource's event, and my solution deletes the user in the GridView's event. Just be aware that `Membership.DeleteUser()` searches for the `UserName` property not the `LoweredUserName` property of the user.

Comment: Yep, thanks for clarification for me! I accept this answer. Thanks for your attention.